# HIDlibrary best way to loop write and read code

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the HIDLibrary and wonder how can I gt this code to loop? I mean send command. Read full response, send command again so on and so on?

The code works with no issues I can get the command, etc. but want to try and make it continuously loop until closed, etc. Later on I'll add more command but want to make it loop first and then take it from there.

Trying to explain more but that's is all I am after but the site keeps saying I need to explain more but there's no more to explain.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HidLibrary;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int VendorId = 1637;
        private const int ProductId = 20833;

        private static HidDevice _device;

        public static string tString1 = null;

        static void Main()
        {
            _device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorId, ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (_device != null)
            {
                _device.OpenDevice();

                _device.Inserted += DeviceAttachedHandler;
                _device.Removed += DeviceRemovedHandler;

                _device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;

                var message = new byte[] { 0, 81, 80, 73, 71, 83, 183, 169, 13 };
                _device.Write(message);

                _device.ReadReport(OnReport);

                Console.WriteLine("Reader found, press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();


                _device.CloseDevice();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find reader.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }


        private static void OnReport(HidReport report)
        {
            if (!_device.IsConnected) { return; }

            var cardData = report.Data;

            tString1 += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cardData);

            if (tString1 != null)
            {
                if (tString1.IndexOf((char)13) > -1)
                {
                    tString1 = tString1.Replace(" ", ",");
                    Console.WriteLine(tString1);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    tString1 = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void DeviceAttachedHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device attached.");
            _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
        }

        private static void DeviceRemovedHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device removed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a while loop which checks for device connection status inside your Main().

```
_device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorId, ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
while (_device.IsConnected)
{
    if (_device == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No device was found");
        return;
    }
    _device.OpenDevice();

    _device.Inserted += DeviceAttachedHandler;
    _device.Removed += DeviceRemovedHandler;

    _device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;

    var message = new byte[] { 0, 81, 80, 73, 71, 83, 183, 169, 13 };
    // Adding a timeout here would prevent hanging issue
    _device.Write(message, 500);

     _device.ReadReport(OnReport);

    //Console.WriteLine("Reader found, press any key to exit.");
    //Console.ReadKey();

    //_device.CloseDevice();
}
```